# How to get the telephone number associated with the SIM in a GSM phone?

Tags: android, gsm, phone-number, sim-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fetch own mobile number in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896715/how-to-fetch-own-mobile-number-in-android)

How to get the telephone number associated with the SIM in a GSM phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

and with following permission in your xml

```
READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Comment: can i get the details in case of dual SIMs are available in my device?

Comment: @prasad.gai- Did u got your answer...coz iam facing same problem n kinda stuck there..!!

Comment: i am getting null while fetching the sim card number

Comment: @AdityaNikhade too late for answer, but I answer for future viewers :) You receive `null`because it is not mandatory to store the phone number on the SIM. i.e. some operators store it in the SIM and some others not.