# Android passing data from application to mobile in android

Tags: android, mobile

I am facing a major issue in one of my android application project. I need help in that issue.

My question is:

I have a simple screen with a edittext and ok button. User needs to enter the mobile number (in the edittext) of the user trying to install the application on his mobile. Now once we click ok, a message is sent to the number that is entered in edittext.

User Inboxbox message contains the message sent from the application. Now i need to verify if the FROM address in the message and the mobile number entered in application(Edittext) matches. How can i achive that.

how can i compare the data entered in the application with my mobile number.

Note: Application is being installed in same mobile.

Please guide me in this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a number verification system and you already have a service that sends out messages? Then one option is to use the "whatsapp approach" and send a PIN code in the message that the user will then type in to the app?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i need to verify it directly instead of sending the verification code and ask the user to type the verification code again. I just need to to verify the mobile number entered in the edittext and the mobile number in which the application is getting installed are same. Is it possible to check the edittext data and the mobile number are same. Is there a possiblility to compare the data input(Application  value) with the mobile number of the device in which app is being installed. If yes how can i achive...

Comment: You could try this method out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163803/how-to-get-the-telephone-number-associated-with-the-sim-in-a-gsm-phone, then you won't need text messages at all.

Comment: I am able to fetch the MSISDN number in Emulator, But not in my android Mobile. I dont know y it is not working on my mobile, but works fine with emulator.