# Get both sim numbers in a dual sim android phone

Tags: android

I want to get both the sim numbers in a dual sim device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163803/how-to-get-the-telephone-number-associated-with-the-sim-in-a-gsm-phone

Comment: but in a dual sim phone, can i get both sim numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198055/what-does-getline1number-return-with-dual-sim-phones

Comment: Do you have any solutions, unflagged.destination?

Comment: no i didn't got any solution for this. I am using default number from them for my application.

Comment: check out this answer :
[Check whether the phone is dual SIM][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Answer (score 9):

Work with API > 21

Need permission `android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.`

```
public class SplahActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private SubscriptionManager mSubscriptionManager;

    public static boolean isMultiSimEnabled = false;
    public static String defaultSimName;

    public static List<SubscriptionInfo> subInfoList;
    public static ArrayList<String> Numbers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splah);

        Numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
        GetCarriorsInformation();

    }

    private void GetCarriorsInformation() {
        subInfoList = mSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        if (subInfoList.size() > 1) {
            isMultiSimEnabled = true;
        }
        for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subInfoList) {
            Numbers.add(subscriptionInfo.getNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

[**SubscriptionManager Api 22 Android Official**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html)

Comment: I try this and subscriptionInfo.getNumber() always return null

Comment: @mindw0rk it will retrun the stored number from your sim settings.[http://i.imgur.com/GsH04DQ.png]

Answer (score 5):

Make this class **TelephonyInfo**.java :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public final class TelephonyInfo {

private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
private String imeiSIM1;
private String imeiSIM2;
private boolean isSIM1Ready;
private boolean isSIM2Ready;

public String getImeiSIM1() {
    return imeiSIM1;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
}*/

public String getImeiSIM2() {
    return imeiSIM2;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
}*/

public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
    return isSIM1Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
}*/

public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
    return isSIM2Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
}*/

public boolean isDualSIM() {
    return imeiSIM2 != null;
}

private TelephonyInfo() {
}

public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

    if(telephonyInfo == null) {

        telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
        telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return telephonyInfo;
}

private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    String imei = null;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            imei = ob_phone.toString();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return imei;
}

private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    boolean isReady = false;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
            if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                isReady = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return isReady;
}


private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

    public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
        super(info);
    }
}
```

}

And then use this class like that:

```
private void isDualSimOrNot(){
    TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

    String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1();
    String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2();

    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();
    Log.i("Dual = "," IME1 : " + imeiSIM1 + "\n" +
            " IME2 : " + imeiSIM2 + "\n" +
            " IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + "\n" +
            " IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + "\n" +
            " IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + "\n");
}
```

Add this permission to the apps AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Above code works perfectly for me.

Comment: You were missing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great answer thank you. just one thing, is there any way to get more info from sim card? specifically i want to know witch operator it's belongs to.  imei is more device related not sim card. am i right?

Comment: not working on Samsung Note 3 Neo (SM-N7502)

IS DUAL SIM: FALSE

Comment: For Android 5.1 and above devices you use Subscription Manager to read both sim info..
If you are working on beow version use alternative method as below

getDeviceIdDS(int slot no)
getDeviceId(int slot no)

Note : getDeviceIdGemini method is not exists in Samsung Neo...You will be use getDeviceIdDS

Comment: Question about sim number (IMSI) but answer about IMEI, which is different

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet for get sim details from dual sim device!

```
  //above 22
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            //for dual sim mobile
            SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);
    
            if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
             //if there are two sims in dual sim mobile
                List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
                SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
                SubscriptionInfo simInfo1 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(1);
    
                final String sim1 = simInfo.getDisplayName().toString();
                final String sim2 = simInfo1.getDisplayName().toString();
    
            }else{
             //if there is 1 sim in dual sim mobile
                TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    
                String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    
            }
    
        }else{
            //below android version 22
                    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    
                    String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        }
```