# Programmatically retrieve IMEI number for dual SIM in android

Tags: android, imei, dual-sim

For single SIM following code works:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei= tm.getDeviceId();
```

For dual SIM I tried code on following link:

[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

But it didnt work for me.

Let me know if any other solutions possible.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472951/get-both-sim-numbers-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: which API version are you targetting? I too am developing a dual-SIM app that needs to work very old phones and new alike.

Answer (score 6):

Try using [`getDeviceId(int slotId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId(int)) added in API level 23.

> Returns the unique device ID of a subscription, for example, the IMEI
>   for GSM and the MEID for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not
>   available.
>
> Requires Permission: `READ_PHONE_STATE`

Answer (score 5):

We can check whether phone single or dual sim by using Android API and IMEI for each sim Card

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single or Dula Sim "+manager.getPhoneCount());
Log.i("OmSai ", "Defualt device ID "+manager.getDeviceId());
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single 1 "+manager.getDeviceId(0));
Log.i("OmSai ", "Single 2 "+manager.getDeviceId(1));
```

Comment: This is used for Android 23+ as mentioned in Android SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getPhoneCount()

Comment: For which version your looking.

Comment: I am looking for API 15+

Comment: getPhoneCount () method is not available

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getFirstMethod = telephonyClass.getMethod("getDeviceId", parameter);
        Log.d("SimData", getFirstMethod.toString());
        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = 0;
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String first = (String) getFirstMethod.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
        Log.d("SimData", "first :" + first);
        obParameter[0] = 1;
        String second = (String) getFirstMethod.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
        Log.d("SimData", "Second :" + second);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

try using this,this should help getting both device id on android lollipop

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can get both IMEI numbers Using this below code

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeiNumber1 = tm.getDeviceId(1); //(API level 23)   
String imeiNumber2 = tm.getDeviceId(2);
```

Comment: I followed your answer but it given me reverse(i got "imeiNumber1" as secondary IMEI and "imeiNumber2" as primary IMEI,then i did more research and got the solution.
`TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeiNumber1 = tm.getDeviceId(0);
String imeiNumber2 = tm.getDeviceId(1);`

Comment: suppose i have to create contact programtically in sim1 and sim2 then can you please tell me what Sim URI we will Use thanx . @user7036069

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager first = (TelephonyManager) getFirstMethod.invoke(null, obParameter);

Log.d(TAG, "Device Id: " + first.getDeviceId() + ", device status: " + first.getSimState() + ", operator: " + first.getNetworkOperator() + "/" + first.getNetworkOperatorName());

obParameter[0] = 1;
TelephonyManager second = (TelephonyManager) getFirstMethod.invoke(null, obParameter);

Log.d(TAG, "Device Id: " + second.getDeviceId() + ", device status: " + second.getSimState()+ ", operator: " + second.getNetworkOperator() + "/" + second.getNetworkOperatorName());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: suppose i have to create contact programtically in sim1 and sim2 then can you please tell me what Sim URI we will Use thanx . @Ravindra Barnwal

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible. The java reflection, you used could work for some devices but not all. However there might be some manufacturer specific API's that allows for this.

Quoting [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996639/1626878),

> Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK. Device
>   manufacturers who have created multi-SIM devices are doing so on their
>   own. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer and see if
>   they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the
>   second SIM.

Comment: This is not correct anymore. You can both imeis in recent versions of Android

Answer (score 0):

Yes Android currently not supported Dual Sim. But you can retrive all possible details by using Java reflection.

I research for fetching dual SIMs details and it works on bellowed devices

Samsung Galaxy Neo 

Moto E

Micromax A52

Micromax Canvas 

Linovo P780

HTC Dreem 

Moto G

LG

HUAWEI Y520-U22

LG-P705

Sony ST26i

I successfully get dual SIM Detials from above models

Comment: SubscriptionManager is a class in which you can get all cell info above android 5.1

Comment: Are you able to get both sims carrier/operator name using Reflections?

Comment: suppose i have to create contact programtically in sim1 and sim2 then can you please tell me what Sim URI we will Use thanx . @user3131373

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get both imei. Sorry for inconvenience. I was in a hurry.

```
public static void samsungTwoSims(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getFirstMethod = telephonyClass.getMethod("getDefault", parameter);

        Log.d(TAG, getFirstMethod.toString());

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = 0;
        TelephonyManager first = (TelephonyManager) getFirstMethod.invoke(null, obParameter);

        Log.d(TAG, "Device Id: " + first.getDeviceId() + ", device status: " + first.getSimState() + ", operator: " + first.getNetworkOperator() + "/" + first.getNetworkOperatorName());

        obParameter[0] = 1;
        TelephonyManager second = (TelephonyManager) getFirstMethod.invoke(null, obParameter);

        Log.d(TAG, "Device Id: " + second.getDeviceId() + ", device status: " + second.getSimState()+ ", operator: " + second.getNetworkOperator() + "/" + second.getNetworkOperatorName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can IMEI in Android O or above.

```
Set<String> deviceIdList = new HashSet<>();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int phoneCount = telephonyManager.getPhoneCount();
for (int i = 0; i < phoneCount; i++) {
   deviceIdList.add(telephonyManager.getImei(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
1 > You must have READ_PHONE_STATE Permission enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

2 > For Android SDK v23<= get SIM 1 & SIM 2 IMEI by this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Log.e("IMEI---1:", tm.getDeviceId(0) );
    Log.e("IMEI---2:", tm.getDeviceId(1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get IMEI Number for an Android Device:

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    btn_imei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_CODE);
                return;
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                for (int i = 0; i < telephonyManager.getPhoneCount(); i++) {
                    stringBuilder.append(telephonyManager.getImei(i));
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
            }
            txt_imei.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

```
    String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM1();
    String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM2();

    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_imei);
    tv.setText(" IME1 : " + imeiSIM1 + "\n" +
            " IME2 : " + imeiSIM2 + "\n" +
            " IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + "\n" +
            " IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + "\n" +
            " IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + "\n");

}
```

Comment: Your answer needs [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and it seems to be missing both part of the code and an explanation.