# How to read two IMEI, from Cell phone Dual SIM? (In Android Studio)

Tags: android, imei, dual-sim

I used this line in Android Studio to get IMEI number,

```
"android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()"
```

and I can see the first IMEI, but I need see the second IMEI.

Update: I checked this link
[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

but I cant resolve the second IMEI.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim

Comment: [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/4741746) this Vaibhav Jani nailed it

Answer (score 0):

Try using getDeviceId(int slotId) added in API level 23.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE‌​);
String imeiNumber1 = tm.getDeviceId(0);
String imeiNumber2 = tm.getDeviceId(1);
```

Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524413/programmatically-retrieve-imei-number-for-dual-sim-in-android

Answer (score 0):

IMEI number is depending on your sim slots if you have triple sim mobile there is 3 imei numbers so best way to find out is Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/4741746)   Vaibhav Jani naild it

Answer (score -3):

Just add 8 to the last three digits of your first `imei` number like:

```
example : 123456789012345 (first imei)
          123456789012353 (second imei)
```

Comment: This is not valid anwser. It does not have to be 8

Comment: Bad answer. This does not fit