# android dev get dual sim carrier name and other info

Tags: android, telephonymanager, dual-sim

```
SubscriptionManager manager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());
List<SubscriptionInfo> list = manager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
```

when I call the above function I get the list of all available sims that are in cell phone. But my question is how to check which sim is the primary one (not in slot one) the one selected for phone calls. I've seen the documentation but found nothing relevant.This can be done using `TelephonyManager`

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

but it only gives the selected sim for phone calls and it only gives one I want both sims name and check which one is active

Comment: may be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088950/how-to-check-which-sim-is-set-as-default-sim-in-android-programatically

Comment: thanks @HammadTariq but it does not work for me it always returns 0 as defaultSimm and -1 as smsDefaultSim regardless of my selection