# How to get both phone number from dual SIM device?

Tags: android

I know how to get user's phone number, but let's say the user's phone is dual SIM. Is there any way to get both phone numbers? Currently I am getting the active phone number only.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472951/get-both-sim-numbers-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the phone number is indeed stored in the SIM card, then you can use subscriptionmanager API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) to get the details on each subscription i.e for each SIM card.

You can call

- getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() which will return list. In your case if there are 2 SIM cards inserted, it should return 2 subscription infos
- In subscription info, you can call getNumber() API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo.html#getNumber()) to get the number

Please note that for this to work, the SIM card should have the phone number in it.

Please note this API is only supported from API level 22

Adding example code :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());
            List<SubscriptionInfo> subsInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

            Log.d("Test", "Current list = " + subsInfoList);

            for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subsInfoList) {

                String number = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();

                Log.d("Test", " Number is  " + number);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will try this now

Comment: subscriptionInfo.getNumber() return null value.

Comment: We are getting Null value. Is there any better alternative or solution of this?

Comment: Second slot sim card number is null.

Comment: if sim card number is null, then need to set number in android phone, using setting -> SIM cards -> then set number in SIM

Answer (score 0):

I have Kotlinized @manishg code (from 5 years ago):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    val subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(applicationContext)
    val subsInfoList = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList
    Log.d("Test", "Current list = $subsInfoList")
    for (subscriptionInfo in subsInfoList) {
        val number = subscriptionInfo.number
        Log.d("Test", " Number is  $number")
    }
}
```

Note #1: you must add to the manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

Note #2: you should have a permission check on your code, like:

```
  val subsInfoList = if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        return
    } else {
        //todo return "no permissions"
    }
```

Comment: on android 11+, it must need READ_PHONE_NUMBER permission