# How to get dual sim serial number in Android

Tags: android

I want to get Sim serial number of both primary and secondary SIM.Currently I am using getSimSerialNumber() method.But using this method I am able to get only primary SIM serial number not secondary.
I want serial number of both SIM.
What is the solution for that?

Comment: I think this is covered by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472951/get-both-sim-numbers-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: See the second answer

Answer (score 0):

SubscriptionManager can be used for it but its cannot be used third party apps by **Android 10  and SubscriptionManager Added in API level 22**

```
// Requires, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
SubscriptionManager sm = SubscriptionManager.from(mContext);

// it returns a list with a SubscriptionInfo instance for each simcard
// there is other methods to retrieve SubscriptionInfos List<SubscriptionInfo> 
sis = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

// getting first SubscriptionInfo
SubscriptionInfo si = sis.get(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You try below code

```
TelephonyManager tManager=(TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: I want to get sim serial number of both sims not IMEI number